# How to make text on button appear and disappear continualy

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a button that I want its text appear for 1 second then disappear for 1 second, loop for 6 seconds, here is what I tried:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++) {
    button.setTextSize(18);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    button.setTextSize(0);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

- first is it appear that the button's text size became 36 instead of 18,
- second is it is does not act as I expected, never show the text,
- note: the text size from start is 0.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Dont use thread, It will waste CPU time and decrease performance of the application

Comment: @Selvin I don't think handler will behave as I expected, because after this code the activity end

Comment: are you trying to apply blink animation on textview?

Comment: yes, that's what I want @vrundpurohit, but it is the button, I just want the text on button blink

Comment: https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations

Comment: you can just apply blink animation on your textview. are aware of android animations?

Answer (score 4):

okey as you suggested you want to just blink your `TextView`, here what you can do.

create on folder under `res` called "anim", now create one xml file under that say

**blink.xml** and copy this code in it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<alpha
     android:fromAlpha="0.0"
     android:toAlpha="1.0"
     android:duration="1000" 
     android:repeatMode="reverse"
     android:repeatCount="infinite" /> 
</set>
```

Now in your Java class just apply this animation to your `TextView`

```
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),
                    R.anim.blink);
yourtextview.startAnimation(anim);
```

Done.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of blocking thread using `Thread.sleep(1000)` you can use `handler` post delayed and after 1 second and make it visible and post another one to make it disappear .

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        /* Make it visible here. */
        button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                /* Make it disappear here. */
                button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }, 1000);      
    }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 3):

This simple code can help you blink your textview:

```
final String text = yourTextView.getText().toString();
TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (yourTextView.getText().length() == 0) {
                    yourTextView.setText(text);
                } else {
                    yourTextView.setText("");
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask,1000,1000);
```